# Subdomain for a different server

Tags: web-hosting, apache, nginx

I have two servers running on different machines(say A and B), there is a middleware which i cannot access, which routes the traffic for website say xyz.com to machine A ip, now I want to route the traffic to a subdomain say test.xyz.com to machine B, how can I do that?
Machine A has apache server running on it and machine B has nginx on it.
Both the machines are under NAT network with a single public IP.

Comment: Is there any reason to not just assign each one a different IP address and let DNS resolve root.www.xyz.com and test.xyz.com (or www.test.xyz.com)?

Comment: I am restricted to host the website under nat, so I don't have two public ip's and the main problem is I don't have access to the middleware so i cannot redirect the traffic to different local ips' all I can access is the machine A